# Convert dds + xml to ttf?

Tags: fonts, truetype, bitmap-fonts

is there a way to convert a DDS file to TTF if I have an XML file with all the characters and their positions? I was googling for multiple hours without any success.

I need it just for 3 fonts, so something free, or at least trial that would allow me to convert at least one font?

Thanks.

Comment: DDS is a type of bitmap, but a very specific one. Try googling again but for *bitmaps* -- in general. Then, if you find a tool that can do this, find a converter for your original files to the necessary input type.

Comment: I was googling a lot for bitmaps and bitmap-fonts etc and found nothing. But I was able to found the font I needed to convert, so somebody already did it. But I still would like to find some tool that could do it. I know only with DDS its hard and I have to do it manualy, but if I have XML file with all info needed, there should be program for that.